# Escrevendo ID da Div faz Aparecer Div Escondida

Tags: php, html, html5

Sei que a pergunta já esta confusa, porém a dúvida é simples mas não faço ideia de como posso fazer, vamos lá.

- Tenho um sistema de login
- A pessoa loga nesse site
- Tem a página inicial, na qual eu quero aplicar o script

### **Ok, mas que script?**

Na minha cabeça está assim: um campo de texto parecido com uma caixa de pesquisa, nela a pessoa vai digitar um ID, o ID seria tanto o ID da div, quanto o código do pedido.

### **Não entendi**

Resumidamente, necessito de uma caixa de pesquisa, na qual há varias div ocultas na página, ao digitar o ID da div na caixa de pesquisa, faz a mesma aparecer.

### **Mas por que você não usa uma caixa de pesquisa normal?**

Porque as DIV ocultas não poderão aparecer para qualquer usuário, pois terão algumas informações, vamos dizer, "pessoais".

Deixo meus agradecimentos a quem leu e muito mais a quem tentar me ajudar.

Por fim, para quem ainda não entendeu a pergunta, la vai: *Como posso criar um campo de pesquisa que ao digitar um ID de uma DIV faz ela aparecer?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho certeza se entendi completamente, mas segue exemplo:

Obs: Será preciso importar o Jquery.

HTML:

```
<label for="txtPesquisa">pesquisa</label>
<input type='text' id='txtPesquisa' />

<div class="pedidos">

  <div id="1" class="hide">
  1
  </div>

  <div id="2" class="hide">
  2
  </div>

  <div id="3" class="hide">
  3
  </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtPesquisa").keyup(function(index){  
    $(".pedidos div").hide();
    $(".pedidos #"+$(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

Segue Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mu16vmnt/

Comment: Exatamente isso amigo , muito obrigado pela ajuda, acredito que vai servir de bom uso a todos do Stack.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, deixe a div em questão com visibility: hidden; depois dentro de seu input utilize  o **onKeyUp**, mais ou menos assim:

```js
if(this.value > 0){ document.getElementById('div_id').style.visibility='visible'; }else{document.getElementById('div_id').style.visibility='hidden';}
```

```css
#div_id {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: não sabia da função onKeyUp, obrigado pela dica e pela ajuda. Vai servir de bom uso amigo

Answer (score 1):

> Deixar os dados em uma div oculta não é nem um pouco seguro, qualquer um pode olhar os dados e alterar (no client side). O ideal é levar para a página somente o que for utilizar e/ou o usuário terá permissão de ver.

Em javascript puro você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```css
div.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script>
function showDiv(e){
 var id = e.value;
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var elements = new Array();
    elements = getElementsByClassName('hide');
    for(i in elements ){
     elements[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if(element){
      element.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function getElementsByClassName(classname, node)  {
    if(!node) node = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}
</script>

<input id="pesquisa" onkeyup="showDiv(this)"/>

<div id="1" class="hide">
1
</div>
<div id="22" class="hide">
22
</div>
```

O código acima está buscando todos os elementos com a classe `hide` na função `getElementsByClassName()`  e ocultando-as. Se possuir algum elemento com o `id` igual ao valor digitado, mostro a `div`.

[Exemplo JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nu2wg1Lf/1/)
Referência: [Hide all elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4644705/4843158)

Comment: Era isso mesmo, @Randrade muito obrigado pela solução e agradeço por compartilhar seu conhecimento comigo e com todos do Stack.